# Can I set a JavaScript function to run, while loading its view from a controller?

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp-2.0

I am using Cakephp and I am loggingout the user from my website using the index function in my logout controller. What is required that when the user logs out, i should be able to run a javascript Logout function.

What i basically want that a particular Javascript function should run when the login page is loaded from logout controller? Either by doing changes here in the controller or by making the changes in the destination view page's javascript.

Here is my index function from the logout controller:-

```
     function index(){
       $isSessionExp = true;

    if( $this->session->userdata('is_sess') )
          $isSessionExp=false;

       $login_session_id = $this->session->userdata('login_session_id');
       $this->login_model->updateLogoutTime($login_session_id);
       $this->session->sess_destroy();

    if($isSessionExp)
       redirect($this->url."/logout/session_expired");
    else
       redirect($this->url."/login");// What I want that I should be able to indicate a particular Javascript function to run after this view is created, ofcourse this behavior should happen only during logout.

     }
```

In the Login class controller I have a index function which is loading the login page. Its code is like this.

```
  class Login extends CI_Controller {

      public function index() {

       if ($this->session->userdata('is_sess'))
           $this->session->sess_destroy();

           $data = array();
           $data['msg'] = null;
           $this->load->view('login', $data);
        }
```

What i basically want that a particular Javascript function should run when the login page is loaded from logout controller.

Is this possible to do?

Any help will be thankfully appreciated.

Comment: redirect($this->url."/login?foo"); then in the controller that produces this view just check for that request var and echo the proper js .

Comment: It's too much easy. Post login function code.

Comment: @silentboy you mean the login function controller code.

Comment: Yeah. Arent you trying to add the script in login.ctp?

Comment: @silentboy sorry for the delay in reply, actually I am doing a Facebook login, in that when the logout happens from my site the logout controller comes into action which in turn destroys the session as shown in the above index function and loads the login page. And what I want to achieve is that on loading the login page again after a logout I should be able to change the facebook login status. For that I need to run a logout function in the script.I am using Facebook javascript sdk for facebook login.

Comment: @silentboy I think i should pass additional variable in the redirect($this->url."/login?foo"); and then in the JavaScript code of the login page I can capture the url and get hold of the variable and accordingly I could run the given logout function or not. What do you say about this?

Comment: Its not matter what is your login or logout logic. But as your code says you must have a function named login. Just show me the function defination. Like `public function login($arg1, $arg2){ //i do not want what you put here }`. I just want to see how much argument they take

Comment: Yeah you are right. But you should pass variable like `redirect($this->uri.'login/bar');` then check it

Comment: @silentboy I have posted the login code.Please Post your answer I will acccept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: answer is updated. Check if not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync your code as mine

```
function index($foo = null){

if($foo)
$this->set('just_logged_out','yeah');
// your codes here
}
```

now redirect like

```
redirect($this->uri.'login/index/bar');
```

now in login.ctp

```
if(isset($just_logged_out))
echo 'you have just logged out';
```

this code isnt tested but should work with or without minor correction. Comment me if you are getting error. But sorry i am on mobile now.

Comment: what I was thinking that a user after having logged in using facebook, I will set in session that this is a Facebook login. On pressing the logout button the logout controller will check for the session and there if it finds that this was Facebook login it will redirect to  redirect($this->uri.'login/index/bar') 
otherwise it will be just redirect($this->url."/login"). 
and then based on value of bar in the url I will call the function to do Javascript logout. Your answer really helped me a lot. Thanks